# meta name in a non canonical amp html?

Tags: html, meta-tags, amp-html

I already have a website where :
1. www.example.com ---> is the desktop version (not-amp)
2. www.example.com/mobile ---> is the mobile version (not-amp)

In the index.htm page of the desktop version, I put :

```
<title>blo blo blo</title>
<meta name="description" content="bla bla bla">
<meta name="keywords" content="blu blu blu">
<link rel="alternate" media="only screen and (max-width: 1024px)"
href="http://www.example.com/mobile/index.php">

<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
if (screen.width <= 1024) {
window.location = "http://www.example.com/mobile/index.php";
}
//-->
</script>
```

And the index.php page of the mobile version, I put :

```
<title>blo blo blo</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="bla bla bla">
<meta name="keywords" content="blu blu blu">
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/index.htm">
```

<sub>Please don't ask me why I have index.htm in desktop version and index.php in mobile version as I myself already forget why I did that a few years ago :).</sub>

Anyway, it works. If I type "www.example.com" in the mobile's browser, then it shows "www.example.com/mobile/index.php" page. If I type "www.example.com" in the desktop's browser, then it shows "www.example.com/index.htm" page.

Now I want to add a new page in a subfolder, but I want to make just one version (which is an amp html page) instead of making two version for the desktop and the mobile.

I read from some articles in the internet that one amp html page is possible meant for both version (desktop and mobile) and from  [here](https://ampbyexample.com/introduction/hello_world/) it say:

> AMP HTML files require a canonical link pointing to the regular HTML.
>   **If no HTML version exists, it should point to itself**.

So, I assume that in this new amp html page in a subfolder, I should put the code something like this :

```
<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.example.com/jewelry/index.html">
```

Where that link is pointing to itself (the amp html index page in jewelry subfolder).

What I want here is something like this :

- www.example.com/index.htm (non-Amp, desktop version)
- www.example.com/mobile/index.php (non-Amp, mobile version)
- a new subfolder (named jewelry) with Amp index.htm file. This link
  will be provided (in a navigation bar) both in example.com/index.htm 
  page and example.com/mobile/index.php page.
- If there are a desktop user and/or a mobile user click that link,
  he/she will landed to example.com/jewelry/index.htm page (amp
  version).

I've been looking around in the internet whether I can put a code in amp html page with meta name like below, but I cannot find it:

```
<meta name="description" content="bla bla bla">
<meta name="keywords" content="blu blu blu">
```

So, my question is :
Can I put meta name "description" and "keywords" in the amp html page ?

Any kind of respond would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Why do you have two versions of your website instead of one version, that's responsive?

Comment: @DanielWilliams, because I thought it's easier for me to just built a new one in a responsive design for mobile version (www.example.com/mobile).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put meta tag in main file non-amp page and also add the tag to make your page discoverable

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://www.example.com/mobile/index.php">
```

Comment: Bachcha, thank you for the answer. Do you mean that in an amp page there can be no meta name "description" and "keywords" ?

Comment: You can put there also, but Google look for main site

Comment: Thank you, Bachcha